# hive posexplode map datatype

Tags: arrays, dictionary, hive, explode

I have datastructure that looks like:

```
ID       purchase_name        purchase_id
A001    {A: a}                {One: 1}
A002    {A: a, B: b}          {One: 1, Two, 2}
A003    {C: a}                {Three: 1}
```

Think of it this way: {A, B, C...} are the brand name (i.e. Nike, Adidas...); {a, b, c...} are the categories under the brand (shirts, shorts, shoes...); (One, Two, Three...} are the internal id for the brand names and (1, 2, 3...) are the internal id for the category names. Now I would like to explode it to:

```
ID      Brand_name Brand_id Category_name Category_id
A001    A          One      a             1
A002    A          One      a             1
A002    B          Two      b             2
A003    C          Three    a             1
```

If there is just one map column to explode, e.g. purchase_name, I am able to use explode to generate brand_name column and category_name column. However, I am trying to use posexplode to get a position variable in order to eliminate multiple rows that would be generated for A001, but I found out that posexplode is only applicable to arrays, not map datatype.